# Есть список его нужно перетасовать все возможный варианты и ввести в список

Tags: python

Есть модуль

```
itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)
```

Место всех возможных комбинаций он выводит:

```
<itertools.combinations_with_replacement object at 0x0000029B814144F0>
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itertools.combinations_with_replacement возвращает итерируемый объект. Если вы хотите его потом много раз использовать, преобразуйте его в полностью хранимую в памяти структуру

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r))
```

или

```
tuple(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r))
```

Если же вы хотите единоразово просмотреть содержимое, то используйте for:

```
for element in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    print(element)
```

Также можете использовать оператор распаковки

```
print(*itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r))
```